# Is there some way for a Jackson Delegate-based Creator to access the raw Json String?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there some way for a Jackson Delegate-based creator to access the raw Json String?

```
@JsonCreator
private static MyClass createFromJson(Map<String, Object> jsonProperties) {
    return new MyClass(rawJson);
}
```

I am able to get the raw input as a Map of Strings to Objects in the code above, but I want to be able to access the json as a string. I tried the code below (based off of http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_457.html) but that code as written is never invoked.

```
@JsonCreator
private static MyClass createFromJson(String rawJson) {
    return new MyClass(rawJson);
}
```

***Note:*** This is a spring boot application (1.3.1.RELEASE) that uses Jackson 2.6.4.

Comment: This is as part of a web application? Why not receive the body as a `@RequestBody` annotated `String` in the handler method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I still want the signature of the controller method to receive and operate on my domain object. In this instance I want to be able to write a 'parseForJson' method that takes an actual json string instead of one that takes a Map.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I *know* spring can give me the raw json, what I want to know is can jackson?

Comment: Why would you need such a thing? If I was writing the Jackson library it's not something I would've thought to include.

Comment: There is no such annotation. Hack: you can receive a `JsonNode` as the parameter type and use its `toString` method to get the corresponding JSON.

Comment: Really, it looks like you want a `JsonDeserializer`.

Comment: @immibis With some further thought, I might not actually want such a thing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for the suggestions, but it appears to me now that requesting the JSON string in this instance defeats the purpose of using jackson in the first place... I will 'answer' this question with this conclusion in the event that anybody else ever finds themselves here...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this type of functionality would not make sense in this context. In fact, it appears to me now that requesting the JSON string in this instance defeats the purpose of using jackson in the first place. However if anyone finds themselves here, then the comments from Sotirios Delimanolis may be useful:

- "Hack: you can receive a JsonNode as the parameter type and use its toString method to get the corresponding JSON."
- "It looks like you want a JsonDeserializer"